# No such directory found in python

Tags: python, anaconda

I am working on Udacity simulator for self driving car. I am trying to load the datasets from myproject/sdc-car/model/training-data.
i am using `ARGS_SERIALIZATION_PATH = "../models/sdc-car/training-args.pkl"` to get the path. However, it seems like it not getting the path.
However, It gives me this error.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../models/sdc-car/training-args.pkl'

Note: my folder structure is `E:/Udacity/newtest/myproject/code-sdc/model/training-data/training-args.pkl`

Comment: The path in your "note" there is nothing like the `ARGS_SERIALIZATION_PATH`.

Comment: This the variable I am storing the path

Comment: ../models/sdc-car/training-args.pkl i am using this script to get the file training-args.pkl. then why i am getting this error

Comment: Change the variable you're setting to match your actual folder structure.

Comment: Use an absolute path. Relative paths are subject to the CWD and your CWD might not be what you think/hope it is.

Comment: Do I need to put actual path? (E:/Udacity/newtest/myproject/code-sdc/model/training-data/training-args.pkl) like this?

Answer (score 0):

- First of all `training-args.pkl` is not a directory. And you have to use the directory path where your all data are stored.
- You can move training-data inside your project directory and then you can load the data easily. use `ARGS_SERIALIZATION_PATH = training-data`